# PHP Generated images aren't inheriting the styles of the containing div

Tags: php, html, css, image, instagram

When using Instagrams API to display the images on my website, the images aren't inheriting the containing divs style.
The style being float:left. So they don't stack on top of each other, they actually appear in rows and columns... rather than just a column.

The CSS:

```
#instagram.img {  
float:left;  
margin:10px;  
}
```

The HTML/PHP (omitting get data & parsing) :

```
<div class="instagram">
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>  
<a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

I tested that, images outside of the php adhere to the styling and they do. They float:left as expected.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, but first of all `#instagram.img` is the `id` selector. It should be `.instagram.img`. Second of all, add the `.instagram`  class to your image or your `<a>`.

Comment: you dont have any element with id instagram, neither do you have any element with class img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.instagram {  
float:left;  
margin:10px;
display: inline-block;  
}
```

As I said in the comment, `#` is the selector for `id`, `.` is the selector for class.

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>  
<a class="group instagram" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img     src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Add the `.instagram` class to your `<a>`, because adding it to your div will float the div left, and not the picture.

See [display properties](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) to see why the `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I get confused with ids and classes... which is a little embarrassing.
I did exactly as you said and they're still not floating.
http://www.care2pets.co.uk/stockport/pet-pictures.php

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` to the class and it should work. I change the answer as well. Cheers!

Comment: Great work - this has cleared up my issue... or inability to tell the difference between ids and classes.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Best of luck!